# Can the teradata connector sqoop sequencefile format overcome delimiter issues?

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

If the database contains fields such as "," and "\n" in the fields, is there a way to sqoop to hive without having to fix those delimiters, possibly using alternate formats instead of standard textfile? Have been working with a few workarounds (ie/ replacing delimiters, oreplace, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've found to overcome this issue on a column-basis for newline characters:

```
SELECT 
  COL_A,
  OREPLACE(COL_B, '0A'XC, '_replace_char_'),
  ...,
  COL_N
FROM
  TABLE_NAME
```

Assumedly this will work for commas as well. I have yet to test if you can nest this replace char statements. Also no estimate yet on the affects on spool-space usage.

The solution is found in the first question, not in the 'answers':

https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Removing-a-line-break-character-in-a-column/td-p/52431

Comment: great answer! Way to go!

Comment: As an update, this appears to not support UNICODE tables, and there are also runtime failures when using this function 100s of times in a single query.